# Is the kanji 様 ever used for san/chan etc.?

Tags: kanji

For example 御母様 ?

I see 御 used instead of お but I have yet to see 様 used instead of さん.

Is it ever used like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. Or I might say "no and yes" because basically no.

さん is originally a colloquial form of 様（さま）, that started to be used since the early modern period. 日本国語大辞典 indeed cites earlier examples with kanji 様:

> ＊浄瑠璃・傾城阿波の鳴門〔１７６８〕八「そして父様（ととサン）や母様（かかサン）と、一所に順礼さんすのか」
> ＊浪花聞書〔１８１９頃〕「様（サン） 男女ともに常言さまといわず観音さん薬師さん抔といふ」
> ＊多情多恨〔１８９６〕〈尾崎紅葉〉前・二「然るに葉山のお種様（サン）は蝋石細工のやうに、硬くて冷たい」

But as さん and さま diverge into each own niche in keigo hierarchy, the situation naturally becomes a headache to everyone, so that in modern orthography 様 exclusively represents さま.

ちゃん is a further development from さん, originally a mimic of young children's pronunciation (like "wabbit"). Likewise there is ちゃま for さま, but this one is not in serious use. I couldn't find evidences where they are written in any form of kanji.

Answer (score 3):

様 is used さま name suffix, not as さん name suffix.

**さん name suffix doesn't have its own kanji** (check reference).

By the way:

There is 漢字 for くん name suffix, 君 (also known as 漢字 for きみ）,
and there is no kanji for ちゃん name suffix.

I hope my answer will help you.

Reference:

https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%95%E3%82%93
https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93